# is this first order differential equation homogeneous?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is exercise 6 of chapter 8.26 in Apostol Calculus I.

I have to solve this first order differential equation :

$$xy'=y-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

The author expained to apply homogeneity property :
$$ y' = f(x,y) = f(tx,ty)$$

with $t=\frac{1}{x}$ and then substitute $v = \frac{y}{x}$ to solve this type of problems. But in this case I'm not sure if it is justifiable (I would use $t=\frac{1}{|x|}$ but this would also yield to a different result), because the ode becomes :

$$y'= \frac{y}{x} - \sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}$$

but if I re-multiply by $x$ I obtain :

$$xy'=y-sgn(x)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

which is clearly not equal to the first one. So, am I right to say that $t= \frac{1}{x}$ can't be performed, while $t= \frac{1}{|x|}$ can be?

Edit :

If I split the domain in $x>0$ amd $x <0$ it seems that when $x<0$ homogeneity can't be applied since I obtain :

$$y'= \frac{y}{x} - \sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}= \frac{y}{x} + \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}$$

Comment: If $x=0$ you wil find arbitrary values provided that $y>0$ (moreover, if $x=0$ the equation is not differential but you can extend the concept to get solutions either way). If $x \neq 0$ then you can divide but will have to discuss different solutions on each half-plane since your solutions can't go through the vertical axis. That's why there is not one solution available on the entire domain.

Comment: Yes, you have to split the domain as discussed in the comment above and add-on, and yes, the proposed solution is only valid on the domain where $x>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xy'=y-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$y(x)=xu(x)$
$$x(u+xu')=xu-\sqrt{x^2+x^2u^2}$$
$$x^2u'=-\sqrt{x^2+x^2u^2}$$
$$x^2u'=-|x|\sqrt{1+u^2}$$
$$-\frac{u'}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=\frac{1}{|x|}$$
I suppose that you can take it from here.

Comment: The OP had a minus sign in front of the square root in the differential equation. It doesn't make a huge difference to the solution, though.

Comment: @md2perpe. Typo corrected. Thanks for the remark..